# Laravel - getQueueableRelations & circular relation

Tags: laravel

Following an upgrade to Laravel 5.6, I have an issue with qeueable models serialization.

After some investigations with Xdebug, it appears that a circular `belongsTo` relation produces an infinite loop while `getQueueableRelations` tries to resolve each model's relations.

*In my `Foo` model:*

```
function selectedItem()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Item::class);
}
```

*In my `Item` model:*

```
function foo()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Foo::class);
}
```

Please note that this legacy code is in the project since Laravel 5.1 and it never produced any issue.

Any idea of how I can solve that without changing this logic?

Comment: Perhaps `selectedItem()` should use `hasOne` method?

Comment: The foreign key is in the Foo model, not in Item.

Answer (score 2):

This was introduced when Laravel added `getQueueableRelations` to the Eloquent model.  You can make it work as it did before by just overriding this method to return an empty array;

See old: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Queue/SerializesAndRestoresModelIdentifiers.php#L23

See new: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Queue/SerializesAndRestoresModelIdentifiers.php#L23

So in your Model you can just do:

```
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getQueueableRelations()
    {
        return [];
    }
```

And your serialization will act as it did before.